# Rewrite to file if that exists in subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a file structure like this:

```
root
 |- public
    |- file.jpeg
    |- file.txt
 |- .htaccess
 |- index.php
```

Now, I want to rewrite `example.com/file.jpeg` to `example.com/public/file.jpeg` and the same for file.txt and every other file inside the `public` directory, but if the file doesn't exists in the subdirectory then rewrite to index.php

For some reason this .htaccess rewrites everything to index.php

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond  %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/$1 -f
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$  public/$1  [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `RewriteCond` to check for existing files/directories from last rule thus **routing everything** to `index.php`.

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# if direct access to /public needs be directed to index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+public [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

# if it is not /public/ then route to index.php
RewriteRule !^public/ index.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: But then other files in the root won't be rewritten, which I want to avoid.

Comment: I think you didn't understand me. I want to rewrite /file.jpeg to /public/file.jpeg if it exists, but every other request to index.php, even directly /public/file.jpeg. Is this possible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70462/discussion-between-anubhava-and-vsakos).

Comment: Yes, it is a valid and existing file, but i don't want it to be accessible as /public/a.jpeg, only as /a.jpeg